# Usage of "shall"

Tags: grammar

Because I shall have done all my exams by then, I'll have much more time next week.

Is this correct? Can we use "conjunction + shall"
If so, when and how do we have to use it?

Comment: You give no example for "conjunction + shall", so I can't say anything about that. However, in American English, _shall_ is limited to two social formulaic phrases, both questions with first person subjects. (1) Singular _Shall I open the window/get you some coffee/leave now?_, which functions as an offer to do something at the addressee's request; and (2)  Plural _Shall we dance/go see a movie/try it out?_, which functions as an invitation to the addressee to do something along with the speaker. Other than these, _shall_ is not used in the USA, and is encounterd only in UK imports.

Comment: No, I meant conjunction +subject+ shall.               As I know " conjunction+ present simple tense is used for future event, and we can not use "shall" and "will" with conjunctions as " when, unless, until, because..."

Comment: You can, but -- as I said -- that's not used in America, except by people attempting to pass as British on paper. I don't believe the old rule is even taught in the schools any more; it was 60 years ago, but nobody believed it, even then.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you actually saying that no American would ever say *I shall have finished by Thursday*? If that be the case it is something I have never noticed in a lifetime of speaking to Americans.

Comment: What, never? No, never. What, neveeer? Well, hardly ever. An American saying that sentence would draw attention to the locution and not the sense, rather like _Wilt thou not?_ It's highly marked; let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

> Because I shall have done all my exams by then, I'll have much more time next week.

This usage of *Because* + *shall* is grammatically acceptable, if unusual and archaic, respectively. While beginning a sentence with *Because* is often employed in casual speech, I wouldn’t recommend it for written usage. Notice that later in the sentence *shall* is replaced with the contraction *I’ll* (I will) which, outside of legal writing, is the more contemporary choice.

An alternative: **I will have much more time next week because I'll have completed my exams by then**.

> [**shall**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shall) *verbal auxiliary*:
>   **1**. *archaic* **a**: will have to : must; **b**: will be able to : can
>
> **2 a**.—used to express a command or exhortation
>
> **2 b**.—used in laws, regulations, or directives to express what is mandatory
>
> **3 a**.—used to express what is inevitable or seems likely to happen in the future  ; **3 b**.—used to express simple futurity
>
> **4**.—used to express determination
>
> [**will**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will) *verbal auxiliary*:
>
> **1**.—used to express desire, choice, willingness, consent, or in negative constructions refusal   <*will* you please stop that racket> 
>   **2**.—used to express frequent, customary, or habitual action or natural tendency or disposition <*will* get angry over nothing> <*will* work one day and loaf the next>
>
> **3**—used to express futurity
>
> **4**.—used to express capability or sufficiency  
>   5.—used to express probability and often equivalent to the simple verb
>
> **6 a**.—used to express determination, insistence, persistence, or willfulness ; **6 b**. —used to express inevitability
>
> **7**.—used to express a command, exhortation, or injunction
>
> **Usage Discussion of *SHALL***
>
> From the reams of pronouncements written about the distinction between *shall* and *will* — dating back as far as the 17th century — it is clear that the rules laid down have never very accurately reflected actual usage. The nationalistic statements of 18th and 19th century British grammarians, who commonly cited the misuses of the Irish, the Scots, and occasionally the Americans, suggest that the traditional rules may have come closest to the usage of southern England. Some modern commentators believe that English usage is still the closest to the traditionally prescribed norms. **Most modern commentators allow that *will* is more common in nearly all uses**. The entries for *shall* and *will* in this dictionary show current usage. (Merriam-Webster *online*)

Perhaps of related interest, is the usage of *shall* or *may* in statutory interpretation.

Use of *shall* and *may* in statutes also mirrors common usage; ordinarily *shall* is mandatory and *may* is merely permissive. These words must be read in their broader statutory context, however, the issue often being whether the statutory directive itself is mandatory or permissive. Use of both words in the same provision can underscore their different meanings, and often the context will confirm that the ordinary meaning of one or the other was intended. Occasionally, however, context will trump ordinary meaning.

Comment: I don't think that the sentence is archaic in *structure*, although the use of 'shall' perhaps is. In fact it's common when 'shall' is replaced by 'will'.  E.g.  *"Because I'll've finished all my exams by then..."*.  I personally regularly use this sort of construction.

Comment: @chasly: my evaluation of *archaic* is exclusively directed at *shall*, as to beginning the sentence with *because*, as I indicated, it is grammatically acceptable. I, too, use it in casual conversation.

Comment: Okay, then we agree :-)